# Problems with importing a project as a module

Tags: android, gradle, module, crashlytics

I have a project X which depends upon several .aar files, `Crashlytics` being one of them. I also have a separate project Y and I'm trying to import the project X as a module to Y.

To achieve that, I did the following changes:

1. Changed `com.android.application` to `com.android.library` in project X
2. Removed the application ID line in project X
3. Added `compile project(":x")` in project Y.

Now, after the gradle build, here's what I get:

> Error:Failed to resolve: com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.5

I'm getting similar errors for all the .aar files that I'm specifically compiling in the dependencies of project X. How to resolve that? Both the projects when run individually, work completely fine.

Here're the gradle files:

[Build.gradle for project Y](http://pastebin.com/xheAVLfv)

[Build.gradle for project X](http://pastebin.com/dwDnLdr6)

Comment: what does your main build.gradle and settings.gradle look like?

Comment: @and_dev, nothing much there. http://pastebin.com/D584eNHN is my main Build.gradle and this: `include ':app', ':princetonReview'` is my settings.gradle

Comment: I think you should first fix the repo linking: https://docs.fabric.io/android/crashlytics/build-tools.html#setting-up-a-library-subproject but i don't think that this causes the issue. Did you call a clean on your project?

Comment: @and_dev, doing it the reverse way worked. Made X as the main module and Y a library.